# How to create "Weekly Boxplots"?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, boxplot

I have dataset which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81rdd.png). I have a data for month of two categories, 62 rows, 31 for each category. I would like to create a weekly boxplots with week number and month on the y-axis [like 01-12, 02-12, 03-12 and so on].

So far I have come up with the following code.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,6))
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp)

sns.boxplot(x=df.index.week, y='Values', data=df, hue='Category', ax=ax)
```

By Using `df.index.week`, I am not getting the expected week value, instead it is giving me the week number of year like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WFIM.png).

Guidance please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a grouping column in your `df` by formatting values from the `Date` column:

```py
date_range = pd.date_range(start='2013-12-01', end='2013-12-31').to_list()
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": date_range + date_range,
        "Values": np.random.randint(1000, 20000, 62),
        "Category": ["anti"] * 31 + ["pro"] * 31,
    }
)
```

Use [`pandas.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to get the week of the year (`%U`) and month (`%m`) joined by a `-`:

```py
df["week_month"] = df["Date"].dt.strftime("%U-%m")
```

(Thanks for the better method [@Cameron Riddell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14278448/cameron-riddell))

Then plot:

```py
sns.boxplot(x="week_month", y="Values", data=df, hue="Category")
```

[image: box plot grouped on week and month]

Comment: You can use `df["Date"].dt.strftime("%U-%m")` instead of performing 2 separate calls to `.dt.strftime`